# Strange database behaviour

Tags: mysql, date

I create in my personal MySQL DB on qnap NAS a date field with the format yyyy-mm-dd.
Sometimes I need to insert in this field date in the form 1880-00-00.
If I use a qnap phpAdmin app to connect to DB through browser I correctly see the value 1880-00-00.

But if I use a client like DBVisualizer, when I run the select on the db, in the data field I see 1879-11-30 rather than 1880-00-00.

How could I get the correct value I inserted in database?

Comment: How did you create your table? Is some calculation being made on the date?

Comment: can you create a sqlfiddle to recreate the strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

`1800-00-00` is not a valid date.

MySQL replaces it with a valid date value.

Here's an explanation of how this work behind the scenes:

```
1800-00-00 ==> 1799-11-30 -- substract 1 month and 1 day from valid 1800-01-01
1800-00-01 ==> 1799-12-01 -- substract 1 month from valid 1800-01-01
1800-01-00 ==> 1799-12-31 -- substract 1 day from valid 1800-01-01
1800-00-31 ==> 1799-12-31 -- substract 1 day from valid 1800-01-01
1800-01-01 ==> 1800-01-01 -- substract nothing, it's a valid date
```

If a date like `1800-00-00` is valid **for you** because you don't know month or a day when an event happened, you should consider changing your column type to `varchar` instead of `date` because in the future you are going to run into problems - especially when using ODBC. Those dates will be empty, as they are not known to that interface.

Of course, you have to be fully aware that you are giving up on building SQL queries that manipulate and calculate over `date` type (specific functions), but if your case is "more or less precise date" such queries wouldn't really give a stable result anyways.